# Django form validates in console, but why not in browser?

Tags: python, django, google-maps, django-forms

I want to test the Google Maps Static API with Django 1.3 (using Python 2.7). For this purpose, I have created a simple form for querying the coordinates (latitude & longitude), the zoom level, and the map size. The form looks like this:

```
from django import forms

class GoogleMapsStaticApiForm(forms.Form):
    latitude = forms.FloatField(required=True, min_value=-90.0, max_value=90.0)
    longitude = forms.FloatField(required=True, min_value=-180.0,max_value=180.0)
    zoom_level = forms.IntegerField(required=True, min_value=0, max_value=21)
    map_width = forms.IntegerField(required=True, min_value=0, max_value=640)
    map_height = forms.IntegerField(required=True, min_value=0, max_value=640)
```

In the respective view, I want to build the URL from the information given in the form and return the URL to a template which should render the map in the same template.

The view:

```
def map_properties(request):
    map_url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GoogleMapsStaticApiForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            center = 'center={0},{1}'.format(form.latitude, form.longitude)
            zoom = 'zoom={0}'.format(form.zoom_level)
            size = 'size={0}x{1}'.format(form.map_width, form.map_height)
            url_suffix = '&'.join((center, zoom, size, 'sensor=false'))
            map_url = ''.join((map_url, url_suffix))
    else:
        form = GoogleMapsStaticApiForm()

    return render_to_response('frontend/frontend.html', 
                          {'form':form, 'map_url':map_url},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Maps Static API - Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {% for field in form %}
                <input type="text" placeholder={{ field.html_name }}>
            {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit">Show the fancy map!</button>
        </form>

        {% if form.is_valid %}
           <p><img src="{{ map_url }}" alt="Google Maps Static Map"></p>
        {% else %}
           <p>Form is not valid</p>
        {% endif %}

    </body>
</html>
```

When I try to validate the form with example data in the Django console, it works fine:

```
>>> from frontend.forms import GoogleMapsStaticApiForm
>>> data = {'latitude':51.477222, 'longitude':0.0, 'zoom_level':12, 'map_width':400, 'map_height':400}
>>> f = GoogleMapsStaticApiForm(data)
>>> f.is_valid()
True
```

But when I enter the same data in the browser and press the submit button, the same template is reloaded but without the generated map. The form never seems to validate. Can anyone please tell me why this is the case? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you display `form.errors` rather than showing "Form is not valid"? Then you'd know why it isn't valid.

Comment: Daniel, I just tried that but `{{ form.errors }}` only always shows that all the fields are required. When I submit the form, the exactly same page is reloaded with the same messages that the fields are required and nothing else.

Comment: Well, as `jpic` says, each HTML field needs to have a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the form is empty because **the input tag does not contain any name nor value attribute**:

```
<input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="{{ field.html_name }}">
```

For the browser to send any data, **the input tag should have a name attribute**:

```
<input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="{{ field.html_name }}" name="{{ field.html_name }}">
```

For an input to show any value, **the input should have a value attribute**. To get the value of a field you'd do `form.data['field_name']`, but we can't do that in the template. So we create a template filter. If you don't know how to do that, **refer to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)**. Here's a quick howto:

1. **Create a templatetags subdir** in your app
2. **Create an empty `__init__.py`** in that directory
3. **Create a file "yourapp_tags.py"** in that directory

Here's an example of the code you could put in that script:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_field_value(field):
    return field.form.data.get(field.name, '')
```

Then you can use it in the template to set the initial field value:

```
<input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="{{ field.html_name }}" name="{{ field.html_name }}" value="{{ field|get_field_value }}">
```

Don't forget to `{% load yourapp_tags %}` in your template or get_field_value won't be recognized !

Comment: Thank you so much, jpic. Although I don't fully understand yet why this works, it works now fine. I will read all this up in the documentation.

The thing is, so far I've only done one project with Django. It used only ModelForms for which the name attribute was never necessary. The Modelform just saved some data into the database and then redirected to a completely different page. I tried to adapt this form structure to my current project, but it obviously didn't work out. Anyway, I'm learning new stuff. That's great. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The underlying trouble you are having is because you have decided to output the form fields via direct HTML, in order to add the `placeholder` attribute, and in doing so you have missed out the most important bit - the `name` attribute. Plus, they won't redisplay the existing values if the form fails validation.

Rather than do this, you should add the placeholder to the form fields themselves:

```
latitude = forms.FloatField(required=True, min_value=-90.0, max_value=90.0,
                       widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'latitude'}))
```

and rely on Django to output them:

```
{% for field in form %}
     {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered, but as this problem relates to iterating over graular form outputs in templates, I thought I'd share how I've formatted it before, and I haven't had any problems with it.

```
<form class="form label-inline" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="field">
            {{ field.errors }}
            <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
            {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="field_help">{{ field.help_text }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div> <!-- end div.field -->
    {% endfor %}

    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" />
</form>
```

It covers errors, hidden inputs, and help_text and it's really helpful for customizing css & html layout. I started using this to better fit the styling of a template I purchased.